# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrix of dimension N that is not Toeplitz

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

From a physics paper, I have the following $N \times N$ tridiagonal matrix $K$, where, for $1 \leq \alpha, \beta \leq N$
$$K_{\alpha \beta}=  \frac{(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})^{2} + l(l+1) + (\alpha-\frac{1}{2})^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}\delta_{\alpha \beta} -\frac{1}{4}\delta_{\alpha 1}\delta_{\beta 1} - \frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha+1)}\delta_{\alpha, \beta+1} - \frac{1}{\beta(\beta+1)}\delta_{\alpha+1, \beta}. $$

We can take $l$ to be a constant. I know that $K$ is tridiagonal and symmetric. Given these facts, is it possible to analytically calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $K$ as a function of $N$?

If a closed-form algebraic expression is not possible, can we find series approximations for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as functions of $N$?

Comment: I doubt you could get an analytic expression for its determinant, much less its eigenvalues. However, you could try treating the off-diagonal terms as a perturbation to the on-diagonal terms. Also, the diagonal term is a little nicer as $(2 + [l(l+1)-1/2]/\alpha^2)\delta_{\alpha\beta}$. You can then fold the $2$ into the eigenvalue.

Comment: I think that by treating the tridiagonal as a product of 2x2 transfer matrices for $[x_{n-1},x_n]\rightarrow[x_{n},x_{n+1}]$ you can relate properties of his product to the eigenvalues of $K$. A bit fuzzy on the details. Sorry.